# PHP Variable in SQL LIKE

Tags: 6, theming

I want to place a PHP variable in SQL LIKE, I tried many ways but no change.

e.g. today $adate is 2012-08-12%

```
$adate =  date("Y-m-d") . '%';
$tvisit = db_result(db_query("SELECT `counter_id` FROM counter_today WHERE `counter_date` LIKE '{$adate}' ORDER BY `counter_id` DESC LIMIT 1"));
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: If you are serious about the theming tag, if you are putting a SQL query into your theme then you should throw away everything you did so far and read a book or two on Drupal and come back. Sorry.

Comment: Can you suggest some books?, Thanks

Comment: Pro Drupal Development by John K. VanDyk is by far the best one out there in my opinion.  But, what I think @chx was getting at is this should be in a module, where content is created, not in a theme, where that content is styled.  Much like HTML and CSS and their division of labor.

Comment: Thanks Jimajamma, which version of drupal this book covers ?

Comment: That one is for D6.   The Definitive Guide to Drupal 7 is my goto for D7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax would be along the lines of:

```
$adate =  date('Y-m-d');
$tvisit = db_result(db_query("SELECT counter_id FROM {counter_today} WHERE counter_date LIKE '%s%%' ORDER BY counter_id DESC LIMIT 1", $adate));
```

The changes from your original:

1. Put {}'s around table name so if you are on a shared database, drupal can put a prefix on automagically.
2. Put LIKE's % in the sql itself, not in the variable.  You need to put in %% since % itself is drupal's way of starting a variable (kinda like \\ to put in a \)
3. Put %s in in front of that for the variable, which is a string.  Remove the {}'s since they are for table names.  Granted, php will find $adate in there since it's all wrapped in ""'s but then you open up yourself to sql injection etc (however remote it would be in this specific example).
4. Put the $adate variable in the function call as an argument.
5. Take out the ``'s surrounding the field/column names.